# Is there a way I can select * from a table with unkown number of columns using an android-sqlite cursor

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to select all columns from a table and return all the rows into a cursor then loop through the cursor to get the columns and use the column names to get values from each column. Then put column name with its value into a JSONObject. But I keep getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundException. is there a way I can select unkown number of columns and rows and map each into a key-value pair.
Below is my code

```
public JSONObject getAllCompanies() {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject();
        Cursor companyCursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM COMPANY", null);
        if (companyCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String column = "";
                String value = "";
                for (int m = 0; m < companyCursor.getColumnCount(); m++) {

                    column = companyCursor.getColumnName(m);
                    value = companyCursor.getString(companyCursor.getColumnIndex(value));

                    Log.i("COLUMN", column + " COLUMN VALUE: " + value);
                    dataArray.put(new JSONObject()
                            .put(column, value));
                }

            }
            while (companyCursor.moveToNext());


            // dataArray.put(dataObject);
            response.put("success", true);
            response.put("statuscode", 200);
            response.put("payload", dataArray);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dbHelper.close();
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> value = companyCursor.getString(companyCursor.getColumnIndex(value));
> ```

Here `getColumnIndex(value)` with `value = ""` returns -1 and that is not a valid index. Since you already have the index in `m`, you can use

```
value = companyCursor.getString(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `getColumnIndex()` needs the column's name as argument.
The name of the column is stored in the variable `column` and not in `value`.
Change to:

```
value = companyCursor.getString(companyCursor.getColumnIndex(column));
```